# execute cat command in subprocess,Popen() of python

Tags: python

If i am running below command then python is returning great result..

`result_aftermatch= subp.Popen('ls -lrt', stdout=subp.PIPE,stderr=subp.PIPE,shell=True)`

but in the same way i have requirement of greping lines from file with Code is as below...

```
list_of_id=[23,34,56,77,88]
result_aftermatch= subp.Popen('egrep','list_of_IDs','/home/bimlesh/python/result.log', stdout=subp.PIPE,stderr=subp.PIPE,shell=True)
result_lines,result_err= result_aftermatch.communicate()
print result_lines
```

Above code is giving error as below...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 144, in <module>
    result_aftermatch= subp.Popen('egrep','list_of_IDs','/home/bimlesh/python/result.log', stdout=subp.PIPE,stderr=subp.PIPE,shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 573, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're passing the command as multiple args. You need to pass them as a list or a tuple.

Like:

```
subp.Popen([ 'egrep','list_of_IDs','/home/bimlesh/python/result.log' ], stdout=subp.PIPE,stderr=subp.PIPE,shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for this:

```
list_of_id = [23,34,56,77,88]
ids_regex = '|'.join([str(i) for i in list_of_id])
result_aftermatch = subp.Popen(['egrep', ids_regex, '/home/bimlesh/python/result.log'], stdout=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.PIPE)
result_lines, result_err = result_aftermatch.communicate()
print result_lines
```

Comment: I tried above but not getting anything in print (no lines, no error).Tried with Shell=True too and getting error " Usage: egrep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `egrep --help' for more information."

Comment: Dear viewers and bloggers , still i did not get correct answer. pls help.